# How to parse 20 digit number using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I parse a 20-digit number using JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: i want to format it to 6 digit decimal places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 20-digit number is generally too big for a JavaScript native numeric type, so you'll need to find a "big number" package to use. Here's one that I've seen mentioned on Stack Overflow and that looks interesting: http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/

That one is just integers. If you need decimal fractions too, you'll have to find something else.

If you just want to check that a 20-digit string *looks like* a number, and you don't need to know the value, you can do that with a regular expression.

Comment: Javascript now has a native `bigint` type - see [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/?search=bigint) - and there are polyfills such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-polyfill) which will use the native type if it's available, or otherwise fall back to using a library which implements the same functionality.

Comment: Yes thanks, this answer is almost 12 years old.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a 20-digit **number** in JavaScript - it'll get floated off on you.

You can keep 20 digits (or 200 or 2000) intact as a string, or as an array of digits, but to do any math on it you need a big integer object or library.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use Number() or parseInt("", [radix]) to parse a string into a real number.

I am guessing you are asking about what happens when the string you parse is above the int - threshold. In this case it greatly depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

There are some libraries that allow working with big numbers such as https://silentmatt.com/biginteger/ - see answer - (did not test it, but it looks OK). Also try searching for BigInt JavaScript or BigMath.

In short: working with VERY large number or exact decimals is a challenge in every programming language and often requires very specific mathematical libraries (which are less convenient and often a lot slower than when you work in "normal" (int/long) areas) - which obviously is not an issue when you REALLY want those big numbers.

Comment: Javcascript doesn't have an "int" threshold because it doesn't have integers - all numbers are IEEE floating point.

Comment: Javascript now has a native `bigint` type - see [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/?search=bigint) - and there are polyfills such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-polyfill) which will use the native type if it's available, or otherwise fall back to using a library which implements the same functionality.