# parseFloat() is not working for large numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a number having 20 precision and 2 scale value using **parseFloat()** function, but when the value of integer part and fractional part exceeds to 14 and 3 respectively **(eg. 55555555555555.33552)**, its not working properly.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this or correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: `parseFloat()` is plain JavaScript and has nothing to do with `jQuery`!

Comment: please check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093744/how-to-parse-20-digit-number-using-java-script-jquery